# Programmatically selecting UICollectionView cell which are not loaded yet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to programmatically scroll to UICollectionView cell using

```
[_calendarView collectionView:_calendarView.calendarCollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexpath];
```

When I retrieve cell using that index path, it gives me nil cell.
I think this cell is not loaded yet. Any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using the below method of UICollectionViewDelegate:

```
- (void)scrollToItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

params-

indexpath : index path of the cell

animated : YES/NO.

scrollPosition : Position of cell when scrolled. choose from following options:

Vertical positions-

```
UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop                  
UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically   
UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom
```

Horizontal Positions-

```
UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft  
UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally 
UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set an instance variable to indicate you want the cell selected.

```
self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
```

Next, scroll to the cell using:

```
[_calendarView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

When returning a cell from `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, compare to the instance variable.  When you have a match, select the cell and then set the instance variable to `nil`.